Adding edges to enlarge vertex cover
Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, and two positive integers $k$ and $\gamma$, decide if there is a set of new edges to be added such that $|E'|=k$, $E' \cap E = \emptyset$ and any subset $V'\subseteq V$ of size $\gamma$ is not a vertex cover of $(V, E\cup E')$.
i.e., can we add $k$ edges to ensures that the minimum vertex cover has a size at least $\gamma+1$.
Clearly, this problem is co-$NP$-hard, even for $k=0$, as this is then the negation of the regular vertex-cover problem. But for general $k$, does this problem allow any approximation algorithms?

Is this homework? Can you reference the place where you saw this problem? What did you try so far?

No, not a homework assignment. But have been thinking about this for a small project. Initial thoughts were based on thinking that. $\Sigma_2^p$ complexity class typically containing a meta problem, whose "yes" instances, typically call for a "no" instance of an $NP$-complete problem. That lead to discussions on approximating some of them. Vertex cover (unlike stable set/clique etc) allow nice constant-factor approximations. Now, what if we consider a problem in $\Sigma_2^p$ etc. So, a bit fluid that way. Possibly, it is the case, that no approximation is possible.

Related question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/168479/msol-for-a-vertex-cover-enlargement-problem
